# Python Regex - Capturing a sentence based on the beginning and ending

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly new to python, but I'm attempting to write a program that will capture a sentence out of a string, based of the beginning and ending of the sentence.

For example if my string was

```
description = "11:26:16 ENTRY 'Insert Imaginative Description of a person' 11:29:17 EXIT 'Insert The Description of the Same Person'"
```

I know how to do the regex to detect the date stamp and the word entry. I'd use:

```
re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ENTRY', description)
```

Which would of course tell me that there was one entry at that position, but how would I make the regex capture the date stamp, entry and the following sentence, but leave out the EXIT log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this.

```
re.search(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d{3})?) ENTRY', description)
```

Use `re.findall` if you want to do a global match since `re.search` would return only the first match.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> description = "11:26:16 ENTRY 'Insert Imaginative Description of a person' 11:29:17 EXIT 'Insert The Description of the Same Person'"
>>> re.search(r'\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d{3})?) ENTRY', description).group(1)
'11:26:16'
```

To get also the log after the `ENTRY`.

```
>>> re.search(r"\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d{3})?) ENTRY '([^']*)'", description).group(1)
'11:26:16'
>>> re.search(r"\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d{3})?) ENTRY '([^']*)'", description).group(2)
'Insert Imaginative Description of a person'
>>> re.search(r"\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d{3})?) ENTRY '([^']*)'", description).group()
"11:26:16 ENTRY 'Insert Imaginative Description of a person'"
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how would I get the log after the ENTRY part?

Comment: The \.\d{3} was a residue from a previous version where I had milliseconds, sorry about that. My expected output was meant to be 11:26:16 ENTRY 'Insert Imaginative Description of a person', because I was then going to put that into a seperate file

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I've never really posted here before, it's the first time. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Add in brackets ( ) around the pattern you want to match to get groups returned for them, plus your pattern doesn't actually match your example - the pattern expects a . and three digits. You can make these optional like this:

```
match = re.search(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3})?) ENTRY', description)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

To capture the sentence, extend the pattern like this:

```
match = re.search(r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3})?) ENTRY \'([^\']+)\'', description)
if match:
    print match.group(1), match.group(3)
```

Note the sentence is in group 3 because the option three digits are group 2.
Output is:

```
11:26:16 Insert Imaginative Description of a person
```

Because the pattern must match the ' ' around the sentence, these are preceded with backslash . Another way of doing this would be to use " " around the whole pattern, in whcih case the ' do not need backslash before them.